# Installing Bugzilla with a sql database on a different drive - how to connect database?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I'm attempting to install Bugzilla on a server with a MySQL database on it already. The database is on E: (for space) and Bugzilla is on C:. Currently Bugzilla does not have a database associated with it, and the perl checksetup script looks for a drive local database.

How can I attempt to get bugzilla to target the database on my other drive? Is there a line I can change in the initial scripts to do this?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but what does the location of the database on one or the other drives ```C: E:``` have to do with BZ's **connection** to the database server? Is MySQL running?

Comment: It would appear that I screwed up. I was using Perl 5.16- some of the scripts for 5.16 are not yet functioning. Beyond that, I had not created a table named "bugs" yet in the database.

Thank you for your help, though. You did get me sniffing along the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help. It wasn't much of an answer but if you click the check mark to accept it, we'll be all done here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell Bugzilla how to connect to the database server in the `localconfig` file.

```
$db_driver = mysql
# The DNS name of the host that the database server runs on.
$db_host = localhost
```

I believe with MySQL you can also directly connect via a local socket.  Be sure to follow the  Bugzilla installation instructions for setting up a database, a database user and password for the connection to use.  The tables will be set up automatically by Bugzilla's setup scripts.

Comment: I'm trying to connect by using the checksetup.pl script; $db_driver = 'mysql' and $db_host = 'localhost'. The error I keep on getting is that it can't connect to the database using the script- access denied for user.